# Difference between Flight path and Route

Tags: flight-planning

What is the Difference between a Route and Flight path

Comment: Can you give us some context so that we can understand your confusion? Because they are really just synonyms: Route, flight path, track, course, etc. all pretty much mean "where the airplane goes"...

Answer (score 1):

Your route of flight is what you plan, planned, or are planning to fly. Your flight path is what you are actually flying or will be flying based on your current track, heading, speed, and attitude. They can be one in the same.

Comment: While I tend to agree (at least in some contexts), I'm not sure those are official definitions. Do you have a source?

Comment: I also tend to agree, but they are really interchangeable depending on the tense.  And I think the source is the English dictionary, these aren't unique terms....

Comment: I think “flight path” is sometimes used to describe the 3 dimensional path through the air. (includes altitude)